# Forcing the discriminant of an integral basis to be a Carmichael number.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, soft-question, algebraic-number-theory

I was thinking about the following lemma recently.

**Lemma**: Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ for some [algebraic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field) $\theta$ and let $n=[K:\mathbb{Q}]$. If $\{\tau_1, \,\dots\,, \tau_n\}$ consists of algebraic integers and the [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant_of_an_algebraic_number_field) $\Delta_{K} [\tau_1 ,\, \dots \,, \tau_n]$ is squarefree, then $\{\tau_1,\, \dots\, ,\,\tau_n\}$ is an integral basis for the [ring of algebraic integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_integers) $\mathcal{O}_{K}$.

[NB: *The converse is not true*: consider, for example, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ with integral basis $\{1, \sqrt{-5}\}$ s.t. $\Delta_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})} (1, \sqrt{-5})=-20$.]

It got me thinking about [Carmichael numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) (simply because they're squarefree) and so I came up with this question:

> How do we restrict $K$ and an integral basis $\mathcal{B}=\{\tau_1,\, \dots\, ,\, \tau_n\}$ for $K$ so that the discriminant $\Delta_{K} (\tau_1,\, \dots \,,\, \tau_n)=C$ is a Carmichael number?

I don't have any coherent ideas, I'm afraid; I hope you don't mind. I've looked around online but I couldn't find anything.

---

*Thoughts*: Looking at the definition of $\Delta_{K}$, we might have to restrict the conjugation maps somewhat to make the prime divisors of $C$ pop out.

**A Frustrated Sub-question:**

> Do such discriminants even exist?

I'm looking at $\sqrt{\pm 561}$ and similar numbers to see if I can find one. See my comments below for a description of a similar attempt that might require a computer programme.

*Why is this interesting?* I don't know: I'm just curious $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I've thrown in the `soft-question` tag for good measure. This question doesn't exactly admit a definite answer.

Comment: Maybe I could take the prime divisors of a Carmichael number, square-root integers close to each of them, then see what I can make of adjoining what I get to $\mathbb{Q}$. That seems like a reasonable approach to finding an example . . .

Comment: I think I'd need a computer programme to implement this approach more effectively :/

Comment: Stickelberger's theorem forces $C\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ since Carmichael numbers are all odd.

Comment: Maybe this is one for MO . . .

Comment: Is this a silly question? The silence is deafening!

Comment: Just to break the silence: I'd be curious too. But it's way outside my ken, I can't even guess how the answer might look like.

Comment: Has anyone found anything? And thank you, @DanielFischer $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, by Stickelberger's Theorem, the discriminant of any number field is $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$.

Conversely, if $d \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ is squarefree, then the discriminant of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is $d$.  An integral basis for the ring of integers in this case is $\{1$, $\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}\}$.

It follows that a Carmichael number is a discriminant of a number field if and only if it is $1$ modulo $4$.  Certainly plenty of Carmichael numbers are $1$ modulo $4$ but not all of them: I believe the first counterexample is $8911$.  It is known that there are infinitely many Carmichael numbers (this is one of the more famous results to have come out of my mathematics department), but I am not a Carmichael expert and I don't know whether there are infinitely many which are $1$ modulo $4$.  Is that part of your question?

Comment: Thank you, Pete! Yeah, I think that's enough, although I did have in mind arbitrary integral bases for arbitrary $\theta$, not necessarily $\theta =\sqrt{C}$ (in my notation). Perhaps that was asking too much; besides, that restriction on $\theta$ is, of course, a restriction on $K$ :)

Comment: In fact, no, that *does* answer the question. I suppose I was expecting any "restrictions" to be much more complicated . . . :)